# Apache Wicket - button is not clickable

Tags: java, wicket

I am really new with Apache Wicket and I have the following request to do:

[image]

When the add button is clicked, a new row should appear with the given name and id input panels.

I have created the green plus button, but is is not clickable.

My code is:

```
addToRight(addBtn = new AjaxSubmitIcon(getRightButtons().newChildId(), "green", ButtonBase.Icon.PLUS_CIRCLE) {
                @Override
                protected void onInitialize() {
                    super.onInitialize();
                    add(new AttributeAppender("style", "position:absolute; right:-3%;top:20px"));
                }

                @Override
                protected void onConfigure() {
                    super.onConfigure();
                    setVisibilityAllowed(true);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onFormSubmitted(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                    send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, WizardStep.REFRESH_PRODUCT_EVENT);
                    target.add(Panel.this);
                    refreshDependingComponents(target);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onValidationError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                    super.onValidationError(target, form);
                    refreshDependingComponents(target);
                }
            });
        }
```

My html:

```
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
<form wicket:id="validatorForm">
    <div wicket:id="addButtons"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div wicket:id="topIdLabelContainer" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <label>
                <wicket:message key="aaaaId"></wicket:message>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div wicket:id="topAmountLabelContainer" class="col-sm-4">
            <label>
                <wicket:message key="bbbbId"></wicket:message>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div wicket:id="data"></div>
</form>
```

Any advice why I canot click on my button? Thank you.

Comment: `AjaxSubmitIcon` is not a core Wicket class, and `addToRight` is not a core Wicket method as far as I know. Unless you include the relevant sources we can't help you

Comment: I guess AjaxSubmitIcon extends AjaxSubmitLink but as Jeroen said we need more details to help you better. Have you tried to debug your code? onFormSubmitted is not called at all? It might simply be some kind of CSS rule that disables your button.